# Jest+React Native Testing Library: How to test an image src?

Tags: jestjs, react-native-testing-library

In my new React Native app, I want to add some Jest tests.

One component renders a background image, which is located directly in the project in `assets` folder.

Now I stumbled about how to test if this image is actually taken from this path, therefore present in the component, and rendered correctly.

I tried using `toHaveStyle` from `@testing-library/jest-native` with a container, which returned the error `toHaveStyle`is not a function. Then I tried the same with `queryByTestId`, same error. When I do     `expect(getByTestId('background').toBeInTheDocument);` then I feel this is useless, because it only checks if an element with this testId is present, but not the image source.

Please, how can I test this? Does it actually make sense to test an image source after all?

Here is my code:

1.) The component that should be tested (`Background`):

```js
const Background: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const image = require('../../../../assets/images/image.jpg');
    
  return (
    <View>
      <ImageBackground testID="background" source={image} style={styles.image}></ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
```

2.) The test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, container} from 'react-native-testing-library';
import {toHaveStyle} from '@testing-library/jest-native';
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
import Background from '../Background';

describe('Background', () => {   
  test('renders Background image', () => {
    const {getByTestId} = render(<Background></Background>);
    expect(getByTestId('background').toBeInTheDocument);

/*    const container = render(<Background background={background}></Background>);
expect(container).toHaveStyle(
  `background-image: url('../../../../assets/images/image.jpg')`,
); */

/*     expect(getByTestId('background')).toHaveStyle(
  `background-image: url('../../../../assets/images/image.jpg')`,
); */

  });
});
```

Answer (score 62):

If you're using `@testing-library/react` rather than `@testing-library/react-native`, and you have an `alt` attribute on your image, you can avoid using `getByDataTestId` and instead use `getByAltText`.

```js
it('uses correct src', async () => {
    const { getByAltText } = await render(<MyComponent />);

    const image = getByAltText('the_alt_text');

    expect(image.src).toContain('the_url');
    // or
    expect(image).toHaveAttribute('src', 'the_url')
});
```

[Documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries).

Unfortunately, it appears that [React Native Testing Library does not include `getByAltText`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api-queries). (Thank you, [@P.Lorand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457417/p-lorand)!)

Comment: `image.getAttribute('src')`

Comment: You can also use `expect(image).toHaveAttribute('src', 'the_url')` ([source](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveattribute))

Comment: I figured it's worth noting that you may never obtain the actual `src` if you have mocked out static assets as noted here via `moduleNameMapper` in the jest config: https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets if you follow their recommendations you'll end up with `test-file-stub` for all `src` on images

Comment: `getByAltText` eh? Seems like a rather *novel* way of finding an image - given that alt-text is what screen readers use (and not what most users see). I was honestly expecting to find a method named `getByImage(src)` or something. Also, you can apparently use `role="img"` as well to get an image (but only works for the `img` tag or similar and not on background images like this).

Comment: @cst1992 Alt text is discoverable by the user on hover in the browser, so I'd argue that alt text is a lot closer to testing the user experience than querying by the src url, even disregarding the usability benefits.

Comment: test by alt text...genius!!!

Answer (score 9):

It's a little hard to say because we can't see `<ImageBackground>` component or what it does... But if it works like an `<img>` component we can do something like this.

Use a selector on the image component through its role / alt text / data-testid:

```js
const { getByDataTestId } = render(<Background background={background}>
</Background>);
```

Then look for an attribute on that component:

```js
expect(getByDataTestId('background')).toHaveAttribute('src', '../../../../assets/images/image.jpg')
```

Comment: I am getting ```getByDataTestId is not a function```

I think they removed it in `@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0`

Answer (score 7):

When I used `getByAltText` and `getByDataTestId` I got `is not a function` error.

So what worked for me was:

```
const imgSource = require('../../../../assets/images/image.jpg');
const { queryByTestId } = render(<MyComponent testID='icon' source={imgSource}/>);
expect(queryByTestId('icon').props.source).toBe(imgSource);
```

I use `@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0`

Comment: this always passes, check `source`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue today and found that if your URI is a URL and not a required file, stitching the source `uri` onto the `testID` works nicely.

```js
export const imageID = 'image_id';
...

<Image testID={`${imageID}_${props.uri}`} ... />
```

#### Test

```js
import {
  imageID
}, from '.';

...


const testURI = 'https://picsum.photos/200';
const { getByTestId } = render(<Component uri={testURI} />);

expect(getByTestId()).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for:

```
const uri = 'http://example.com';
const accessibilityLabel = 'Describe the image here';

const { getByA11yLabel } = render (
  <Image
    source={{ uri }}
    accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
  />
);

const imageEl = getByA11yLabel(accessibilityLabel);
expect(imageEl.props.source.uri).toBe(uri);
```